# How to change the deployment location for a web app deployed by VSCode?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-web-app-service

I'm deploying a Django web application from VSCode, to Azure.
When deployed I noticed that my app is assigned to 'Central US', and I would like it to be in 'UK South'. The deployment procedure doesn't ask me for the location, but I noticed in the application Json file settings file -

```
"id": ...
"name": ...
"kind": ...
"location": "Central US",
"type": ...
"state": ...
```

I think this is an auto-generated file, so how can I change this setting pre-deployment?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to creating and deploying the app within VSCode.
In the 'APP SERVICE' section the Azure tab (on the left), right click and choose

```
'Create new web app... (advanced)'
```

It will ask you a few more questions, including what resource group to use and creation of a service plan, with an option to choose the location.